# Material design look for ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

How can i use material design feature for aggrid? In my angular2 application i have used ag-grid and mentioned the class name as `ag-material` and set the row height to `48`. But material design look doesnt apply for my grid. Should i include any CSS file in my index or it will take from the aggrid packages? 
This is how i applied ag-material class to the grid and overrided the row height at the end.

```
            <ag-grid-ng2  style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
                     class="ag-material"
                     [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                     [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
                     [rowData]="rowData"
                     rowSelection="single"
                     (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged()"
                     rowHeight="48">
        </ag-grid-ng2>
```

can somebody help me in getting material design look for aggrid ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guide on the [angular 2 implementation](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angular-2-data-grid/index.php) says

> You will need to include the CSS for ag-Grid, either directly inside your html page, or as part of creating your bundle if bundling.

and then it demonstrates including the stylesheets needed:

```
<link href="node_modules/ag-grid/styles/ag-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="node_modules/ag-grid/styles/theme-fresh.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Looking into the [github repo](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/tree/master/dist/styles) it shows that there is a separate stylesheet for the material theme that you would need to include:

```
<link href="node_modules/ag-grid/styles/theme-material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```